# Syntax error at end of if statement

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

When I run this code, I get a syntax error at the : symbol in the following line ==>
if (total_size != ((len(fleet_grid)*len(fleet_grid[0])-total_size)):

Why is that?

```
def validate_character_count(fleet_grid, ship_characters, ship_sizes):
"""(list of list of str, list of str, list of int) -> bool
Checks that the fleet on the grid matches the character and size description

"""

    validity = True
    total_size = 0

     for size in ship_sizes:
        total_size += int(size)
     for row in fleet_grid:
        for position in row:
            if not (position.isnumeric() and position.isalpha()):
                total_size += 1
                if (total_size != ((len(fleet_grid)*len(fleet_grid[0])-total_size)):
                    validity = False
```

Comment: Yes, that's because your parens don't match. Didn't the error tell you that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing closing ')'. I recommend you to read the output when you run the program. Preferably in `ipython`
If you write something like that: `if(some_variable:`

The output will be

`In [8]:   File "your_file.py", line 13
    if(some_variable:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

possibly missing closing ')' ?
you have 5 '(' but 4 of ')'

Answer (score 0):

That would be because there is an extra pair of opening braces in the statement

```
if (total_size != ((len(fleet_grid)*len(fleet_grid[0])-total_size)):
```

Here, you have two (( before len.